# How can I divide a table into pages without using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table with about 14000 rows and I want to split the table into 1400 pages(10 rows each) and on changing the page I wanna read some data with AJAX... How is it possible? I don't want to use Bootstrap table datatype or anything...

Any solution?
Thanks in advance. :)

Here is my table :

```
<?php                                          
    echo '<table id="table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <th>username</th>
            <th>service</th>
            <th>Date_created</th>
            <th></th>
        </thead>';

        foreach($$list as &$res){
            $username = $res['username'];
            $group = $res['service'];
            $cr = $res['creation'];



            echo "
            <tbody>
                <td>$username</td>
                <td>$group</td>
                <td>$cr</td>
                <td><button type='button' rel='tooltip' title='More info' class='btn btn-primary btn-link btn-  sm' onclick='userDetailsModal(`$username`)'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></button></td>
            </tbody>
            ";
        }


        echo '</table>
    </div>';
?>
```

Comment: We need to see the relevant parts of your code in order to help

Comment: if you don't want to use any libraries, it's going to be _a ton_ of work to get this working consistently....

Comment: you can create your own pagination or use datatable.net  or https://phppot.com/php/ajax-pagination-with-php/

Comment: My bet, using an external library, is also [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: @Gershom I updated my question

Comment: @dandavis Any similiar solution or I can do what I mean in a different way ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 Thank u useful lib...

Comment: This is a bunch of questions in one. You need to 1) create an ajax request for only a segment of your data, 2) process that request with php and form a db query, 3) perform a db query for only a limited number of results (1400 in your case), 4) respond with that data, and 5) receive the data and update your UI (html)

Comment: @Gershom I know the way man... My problem is the UI. I need to use some ui for doing this stuff...

Comment: You may want to modify your question to focus only on the the ui aspect (specifically, how to take data received from a successful ajax query and insert it into the ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library build in php

https://phppot.com/php/ajax-pagination-with-php/

or you can use https://datatables.net/ plugin along with ajax in php.

Comment: Using [phppot pagination](https://phppot.com/php/ajax-pagination-with-php/) did the trick... tnx.  [datatables lib](https://datatables.net/) wasn't a good choice for me ! Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote also. Same here, i also not prefer datatable but another is simple one.

Answer (score 0):

If someone held a gun to me while coding and wouldn't allow a lib, I would take something like this approach:

```
<table id=tab1>
  <tbody id=t1 class=active><tr><td>a</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody id=t2><tr><td>b</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody id=t3><tr><td>c</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
<style> tbody:not(.active) { display: none;} </style>
```

I would generate the tbody with an ES6 template string by looping the ajax response array to set `tab1.innerHTML`. Your bodies will have many rows, and your rows many columns, but the tbody "trick" is key here. You then set a class of `active` on one tbody to show that page. You will need to figure out a dropdown or breadcrumb or page list widget at the bottom to `document.querySelector("#tab1 .active").classList.remove("active");` and set active on the selected page.

Comment: One problem this can have is that I have too many rows and I need to load 10 rows from my data to each page so the page reloads faster.

Comment: You start a new tbody for every ten rows, which works fine with the above markup. perhaps ask a more targeted question about how to group ajax response array data into groups of ten if you're stuck.